# Getting :after styling to display behind element

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having trouble getting my pseudo element to show up behind the parent element. I am trying to create a button that looks like this:

[image]

however I can't figure out how to get the brown to display behind the button. All I'm getting is this:

[image]

My styling is:

```
.orangeBorderedButton{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative; 
    margin:10px 25px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    z-index: 3;
}
.orangeBorderedButton:after{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $orange;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: 2px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle on jsfiddle.net so we can play around with it please? It´s much easier to help you with that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zt4yufx0/4/ @MarcelWasilewski

Comment: if it is for a button effect, box-shadow can do the job http://jsfiddle.net/zt4yufx0/21/

Comment: There is a problem in defining **background-color: $orange;** . You have to add  background-color in  .orangeBorderedButton{ } also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just turn your css around and give the background to the button and not the after element, and you should be good.

http://jsfiddle.net/zt4yufx0/28/

```css
body{
  background:black;
}

.orangeBorderedButton{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative; 
  margin:10px 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #aa7936;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 7px 15px 3px 25px;
}
.orangeBorderedButton:after{
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: -5px; 
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index:-5;
}
```

```html
<a data-sr>
  <button class="button large orangeBorderedButton">See All</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use background color in button CSS and give border to :after, See this code

```
 .orangeBorderedButton{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative; 
    margin:10px 25px;
    background-color: #aa7936;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.orangeBorderedButton:after{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid white;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```